# Default distance between axis numbers and axis labels pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

What is the default distance between the axis numbers and axis labels in the plots made with pgfplots?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default distance between the tick labels and the axis labels when using `compat=1.3` or later (and thus `xlabel near ticks`) is `2*inner sep + 2*outer sep = 2*0.3333em + 2*0.5\pgflinewidth`.

If you're not using `compat=1.3` (or explicitly supply `xlabel absolute`), the distance between the top of the x label and the x axis is `15pt`, and the distance between the horizontal centre of the y label and the y axis is `35pt`.

Comment: +1: how did you find this out? studying the source?

Comment: ok ! thanks how i can set up this distance: "2*inner sep + 2*outer sep = 2*0.3333em + 2*0.5\pgflinewidth" i use compat=newest

Comment: @FormlessCloud: The distance is set up automatically when you use `compat=newest`.

Comment: even if I manually changed the distance from the grid of the tick labels with this command: yticklabel shift = 2pt xticklabel shift = 2pt ?

Comment: @FormlessCloud: Yes, if you use `compat=newest` and you have a version of PGFplots >= 1.3 then the distance between the tick labels and the axis labels will be kept automatically.

Comment: i have added one screen of my plot... see the distance is not too large? and the distance between the axis label and the colorbar is right? should not be equal to the distance that exists between the ticks and axis labels labels?

Comment: @cmhughes: From the documentation (both for PGFplots and for PGF) and through trying it out.